# How did The Doctor end up outside and Clara lost inside when TARDIS was zapped by the scavengers?

Tags: doctor-who

In the *Doctor Who* episode *Journey to the Center of the TARDIS*, The Doctor turned off the shield of TARDIS and suddenly scavengers zapped it and pulled it inside. When they dumped the TARDIS, the gate of TARDIS was still closed, but The Doctor was outside. How? As I recalled, opening the doors required efforts, too (meaning doors weren't soft shut).

Comment: Good question. And I'd also add "why wasn't clara in the console room but got lost inside the TARDIS instead?"

Comment: @tilley31 That can be TARDIS malfunction (internal matter is reprogrammable) which could only be fixed using the *Wobbly Switch*.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since the [show script](http://jpgr.livejournal.com/157814.html) is no help, if I had to hazard a guess I'd say that when the TARDIS detected the exploding console, it transported the Doctor and Clara to the nearest safe point outside the blast radius. Since the Doctor had his back to the door, it moved him outside and into the pressurised hangar. Because the explosion was between Clara and the Doctor, it moved her in the opposite direction into an adjacent corridor a similar distance away from the explosion (but still inside the TARDIS).

We see an almost identical situation in "[The Doctor's Wife](http://jpgr.livejournal.com/120390.html)", albeit in reverse, removing the inhabitants of a room in danger and moving them *into* main control room:

> The four of them materialize in the console room.
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Yes. I mean you could do that, but it just won't work.
>   Hardwired fail-safe. **Living things from rooms that are deleted are
>   automatically deposited in the main control room.** But thanks for the
>   lift!*

Comment: Throwing someone outside the Tardis seems incredibly stupid thing to do.

Comment: @cde - "Placing" seems more appropriate. Also, given the choice between being put off the TARDIS or choking to death, I know which I'd pick.

Comment: But it could have just as easily placed them in the same room, the safer choice

Comment: @cde - Assuming the Console room is *actually* adjacent to the exit, my guess is that it moved them to the nearest safe point **away from the direction** of the explosion.

Comment: I always assumed it was as simple as "he fell out the door and she fell into a hallway." The fact that the door subsequently got jammed shut doesn't mean he wasn't thrown free first.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I've watched the scene on playback and the Doctor appears to fall to the floor rather than being blasted outwards. In the next scene we see the ship being lowered into a pressurised hangar. This is presumably the closest safe point for the TARDIS to deposit him which is why he ends up next to it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - At the point of the explosion, the ship is in space. Had he fallen out of the door, he'd have died.

Comment: But, if TARDIS was able to hold Doctor during explosion, what was the point of kicking him outside afterwards?

Comment: Also, why didn't TARDIS kick Clara outside too? Providing it was able to smartly place Doctor post explosion, it could easily do that for Clara.

Comment: Also, TARDIS was malfunctioned. How could it push Doctor outside long after the zapping?

Comment: Also, when did TARDIS get the ability of teleportation?

Comment: @SS it's a dimensional displacement machine, technically thats teleportation. But we see it in S06e04,  when "House" tries to delete the room the scoobies are in, they get teleported to the main room instead. How it works outside of the tardis is questionable.

Comment: @cde - Actually, it was seen teleporting Eleven onto (and off of) the Dalek ship at the beginning of *The Time of the Doctor* and Twelve mentioned it failing when the Boneless were draining the TARDIS' dimensional energy during *Flatline*.

Comment: @Nathan2055 The Doctor's Wife happened before either of those two episodes, as did Journey to the Center that OP is asking about :P

Comment: @cde - Yes, and I assume that the emergency teleporter is an entirely separate system, I was just pointing out that the TARDIS did indeed have a teleporter that could reach outside of the the TARDIS dimension.

Comment: @Nathan2055 Yeah, TARDIS has teleportation system on-board. Thanks.